# Replace status bar with own view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, offset, uistatusbar

I would like to replace the UIStatusBar in my app with my own view.

[image]

I'm assuming that I need to hide the status bar - is this right?

The problem with hiding the status bar is that the navigation bar moves up to occupy it's original position.  How can I add my view and move everything back down 20 px?

[image]

Assuming that I don't have to remove the status bar, but instead can just cover it with my view, I then have the problem of the background color.  This changes between views, so I would need to mask out the existing status bar text - how do I do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: follow this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/) . hope this will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct with a little tweak with self.view's frame.

Add below method to your viewController,

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.view.frame =CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
}
```

Above method moves your view by 20 pixels down.

Comment: I don't want to move the whole screen down - just the navigation bar.  And I can do that by using self.navigationController.navigationBar instead of self.view. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to hide the status bar. In iOS 7, you can do this by adding the `prefersStatusBarHidden` `function`, like so:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

This will hide the status bar.

To fix the movement issue you mentioned, you need to set the status bar style for the `viewController` to `none` (in the interface editor).

Start off by selecting the `View Controller` in the left side panel:

[image: vc]

Head over to the Attributes Inspector on the right side of Xcode, and set `Status Bar` to `none`:

[image: ins]
[image]

That's it, now you can add your own view at the top of the screen with your own content :)

Comment: Side note: If you have written your UI objects programatically, you can set the `Status Bar` style to `none` programatically too ofc.

Comment: The UINavigationBar still start at y=0.  How can I move this down to y=20 so that I can insert my view above the navigation bar?

Comment: You can disable auto layout and set the navBar's `y` to 20 like so: `[navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(navBar.frame.x, 20, navBar.frame.width, navBar.frame.height)];`.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the status bar completely in iOS7, set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO in Info.plist, and `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using autolayout. So for doing that just place all of your views inside another view and in delta y put 20px for ios6/7. and don't forget to follow Audun Kjelstrup's step. Hope it will solve your problem.